# Using display: none VS a SPA approach, when it comes to SEO and performance

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, javascript, react-js, dom

Say I have a component like,

```
// first approach (SPA)
const Component = () => {
  const [show, toggle] = React.useReducer(show => !show, false)

  return (
    <div>
      {show && <div>content1</div>}
      {!show && <div>content2</div>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

And say I decide to rewrite it as,

```
// second approach (toggling 'display' attribute)
const Component = () => {
  const [show, toggle] = React.useReducer(show => !show, false)

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={!show ? { display: 'none' } : {}}>content1</div>
      <div style={show ? { display: 'none' } : {}}>content2</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I'm not 100% sure if the first approach would be considered 'SPA,' but that's usually how I write my SPAs, so I'll just refer to it as such; but I digress.

My question is, as far as SEO and performance are concerned, which would be a better approach in each case?

I know web crawlers love content. If I'm not mistaken, web crawlers wouldn't be able to see the hidden `div` in the SPA approach, so they'd miss/not see this content. But in the second approach, the DOM nodes are there — just the currently 'hidden' `div` is not visible to the user. And it's not like I'm setting `visibility` to `hidden`, so that's why I'm assuming web crawlers can see the content, which makes it good for SEO.

As far as performance is concerned, I would imagine the first SPA approach would be much better suited in that respect, because the DOM would be less populated.

Is my thinking correct? Would taking the second approach be better for SEO and, if so, would it be at the expense of performance?

Comment: "And it's not like I'm setting `visibility` to `hidden`" - Although you do appear to be setting `display: none` - which is an arguably _bigger_ signal?

Comment: I meant that `display:none` means it's available in the DOM whereas with `visibility:hidden`, the tag isn't there, if I'm not mistaken.